# Cumulative time with reset

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, difftime

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
id      land    datetime
pb1     0       2004-04-05 01:44:00
pb1     1       2004-04-05 02:00:00
pb1     1       2004-04-05 16:00:00 
pb2     1       2004-04-05 18:01:00 
pb2     1       2004-04-05 20:00:00   

library(data.table) 
DT = data.table(
  id = c("pb1", "pb1", "pb1", "pb2", "pb2"), 
  land = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
  datetime = sprintf("2004-04-05 %02d:%02d:00", 
                     c(1, 2, 16, 18, 20), 
                     c(44, 0, 0, 1, 0))
)
```

I would like to make a column that cumulatively adds time (in days) but ONLY if there is a '1' in the `land` column. I also would like the count to reset when the `id` changes.

I have tried a variety of methods using `data.table`, `rleid`, and even a nested `for` loop with no success. I have gotten errors using code like this:

```
DT[, total :=land*diff(as.numeric(datetime)), .(id, rleid(land))]
```

I have tried variations of the solution here:  [Calculating cumulative time in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089710/calculating-cumulative-time-in-r)

I'm not sure the best way to calculate the time interval (no success with `difftime` or `lubridate`).

I want the end result to look like this:

```
id      land           datetime         cumtime.land
pb1     0       2004-04-05 01:44:00     0
pb1     1       2004-04-05 02:00:00     0
pb1     1       2004-04-06 16:00:00     1.58333
pb2     1       2004-04-05 18:00:00     0
pb2     1       2004-04-05 20:00:00     0.08333
```

Comment: Oops, typo, sorry. I changed it accordingly.

Comment: Are you looking for this: `all[, total := c(0, land * diff(as.numeric(datetime) / 86400)), by = .(id, rleid(land))]` ?

Comment: btw: don't use function names as object names, it might confuse R; see also `?all`

Comment: Could you add one more line of `pb1` in your example ? I'm not sure about the exact nature of your question.

Comment: the `datetime` result in your "desired results" doesn't match that in your initial input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not replicate @Japp's comment, but you can easily do this with `dplyr`.

Depending on what your exact expected output is, you could stop before the `summarize` call:

```
library(dplyr)
df=read.table(text=
    "id      land    datetime
    pb1     0       '2004-04-05 01:44:00'
    pb1     1       '2004-04-05 02:00:00'
    pb1     1       '2004-04-06 16:00:00'
    pb1     1       '2004-04-07 16:00:00'
    pb2     1       '2004-04-05 18:00:00' 
    pb2     1       '2004-04-05 20:00:00'", header=T) %>% 
  mutate(datetime=as.POSIXct(datetime,format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

x = df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(id, datetime) %>% 
  mutate(time.land=ifelse(land==0 | is.na(lag(land)) | lag(land)==0, 
                             0,
                             difftime(datetime, lag(datetime), units="days"))) %>% 
  mutate(cumtime.land=time.land + ifelse(is.na(lag(time.land)), 0, lag(time.land)))

  id     land datetime            time.land cumtime.land
  <fct> <int> <dttm>                  <dbl>        <dbl>
1 pb1       0 2004-04-05 01:44:00    0            0     
2 pb1       1 2004-04-05 02:00:00    0            0     
3 pb1       1 2004-04-06 16:00:00    1.58         1.58  
4 pb1       1 2004-04-07 16:00:00    1            2.58  
5 pb2       1 2004-04-05 18:00:00    0            0     
6 pb2       1 2004-04-05 20:00:00    0.0833       0.0833
```

The key is to use the `dplyr::lag()` function which takes the "line just above" in the table (which implies that you have to `arrange()` it beforehand).

By wrapping this inside the `ifelse`, I'm checking that `land` and previous `land` were not `0` (and that we are not in the first line of the `id`, or `lag(anything)` will be missing).

I then just reuse the `lag()` function to get the `cumtime.land` variable.

Comment: Thank you, @DanChaltiel! This is SUPER close to what I want. The only thing is I'd like the cumtime.land column to be cumulative. For example, in x[4,4] I'd like to see the value 2.58 instead of 1.

Comment: Is this better :-) ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're after:

```
DT[land == 1, cumtime.land = 
     cumsum(c(0, diff(as.numeric(datetime))))/86400, by = id]
```

`as.numeric(datetime)` converts it to *seconds* so we use 86400 to convert to *days*.

Somewhat more "official" in the sense of leveraging time/date classes directly is to use `difftime` and `shift`:

```
DT[land == 1, by = id,
   cumtime.land := 
     cumsum(as.double(difftime(
       datetime, shift(datetime, fill = datetime[1L]), units = 'days'
     )))]
```

I switched the order of the `by` argument simply to help with formatting.

We use `datetime[1L]` to fill so that the initial difference is 0; we need `as.double` because `cumsum` errors as it's not confident how to deal with `difftime` objects as input.

See also:

- [Calculate cumsum() while ignoring NA values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576358/calculate-cumsum-while-ignoring-na-values)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40227629/3576984