# Sum cumulative time between changes in a single status variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I've been looking for answers and messing around with my code for a couple hours. I have a dataset that looks like the following for a specific ID:

```
# A tibble: 14 × 3
        ID state orderDate          
     <dbl> <chr> <dttm>             
 1 4227631 1     2022-03-14 19:00:00
 2 4227631 1     2022-03-14 20:00:00
 3 4227631 1     2022-03-15 11:00:00
 4 4227631 0     2022-03-15 11:00:00
 5 4227631 1     2022-03-15 20:00:00
 6 4227631 1     2022-03-16 04:00:00
 7 4227631 0     2022-03-16 04:00:00
 8 4227631 1     2022-03-16 05:00:00
 9 4227631 0     2022-03-16 13:00:00
10 4227631 1     2022-03-16 15:00:00
```

This occurs for hundreds of IDs. For this example, I am using dplyr to `group_by` ID. I only care when status changes between values, not if it stays the same.

**I want to calculate the cumulative time each ID remains in status 1.** The instances where status 1 is repeated multiple times before it changes should be ignored. I have been planning to use lubridate and dplyr to perform the analysis.

Tibble I am using for this example:

```
structure(list(ID = c(4227631, 4227631, 4227631, 4227631, 4227631, 
4227631, 4227631, 4227631, 4227631, 4227631), state = c("1", 
"1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1"), orderDate = structure(c(1647284400, 
1647288000, 1647342000, 1647342000, 1647374400, 1647403200, 1647403200, 
1647406800, 1647435600, 1647442800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I've tried various solutions such as [Cumulative time with reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53874810/cumulative-time-with-reset) however I'm having trouble with `lag` and incorporating it into this specific analysis.

The expected output would maybe look something like this:

[image]

And then I would plan to sum all statusOne together to figure out cumulative time spent in this state.

*Invite all more elegant solutions or if someone has a link to a prior question.*

---

**EDIT**
Using solution below I figured it out!
The solution didn't look at the situations where state 0 immediately followed state 1 and we wanted to look at the total time elapsed between these states.

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(max = cumsum(ifelse(orderName == lag(orderName, default = "1"), 0, 1))) %>%
  mutate(hours1 = ifelse(max == lag(max) &
                           orderName=="1", difftime(orderDate, lag(orderDate), units = "h"), NA))  %>% 
  mutate(hours2 = ifelse(orderName=="0" & lag(orderName)=="1", 
                         difftime(orderDate, lag(orderDate), units = "h"), NA)) %>% 
  mutate(hours1 = replace_na(hours1, 0), 
         hours2 = replace_na(hours2, 0)) %>% 
  mutate(hours = hours1+hours2) %>% 
  select(-hours1, -hours2) %>% 
  summarise(total_hours = sum(hours, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(total_hours!=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is far from elegant, but at least it appears to provide the correct answer:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(ID = c(4227631, 4227631, 4227631, 4227631, 4227631, 
                            4227631, 4227631, 4227631, 4227631, 4227631),
                     state = c("1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1"),
                     orderDate = structure(c(1647284400, 1647288000, 1647342000, 
                                             1647342000, 1647374400, 1647403200,
                                             1647403200, 1647406800, 1647435600, 
                                             1647442800), 
                                           tzone = "UTC",
                                           class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))),
                row.names = c(NA, -10L),
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(tmp = ifelse(state == lag(state, default = "1"), 0, 1),
         max = cumsum(tmp)) %>%
  mutate(hours = ifelse(max == lag(max), difftime(orderDate, lag(orderDate), units = "h"), NA)) %>%
  select(-tmp)

df3 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(max) %>%
  summarise(max, statusOne = sum(hours, na.rm = TRUE))

df4 <- left_join(df2, df3, by = "max") %>%
  distinct() %>%
  select(-c(max, hours)) %>%
  mutate(statusOne = ifelse(statusOne != 0 & lag(statusOne, default = 1) == statusOne, 0, statusOne))

df4
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#> # Groups:   ID [1]
#>         ID state orderDate           statusOne
#>      <dbl> <chr> <dttm>                  <dbl>
#>  1 4227631 1     2022-03-14 19:00:00        16
#>  2 4227631 1     2022-03-14 20:00:00         0
#>  3 4227631 1     2022-03-15 11:00:00         0
#>  4 4227631 0     2022-03-15 11:00:00         0
#>  5 4227631 1     2022-03-15 20:00:00         8
#>  6 4227631 1     2022-03-16 04:00:00         0
#>  7 4227631 0     2022-03-16 04:00:00         0
#>  8 4227631 1     2022-03-16 05:00:00         0
#>  9 4227631 0     2022-03-16 13:00:00         0
#> 10 4227631 1     2022-03-16 15:00:00         0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### Edit

It's a lot more straightforward to get the total_hours state=1 for each ID:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(max = cumsum(ifelse(state == lag(state, default = "1"), 0, 1))) %>%
  mutate(hours = ifelse(max == lag(max), difftime(orderDate, lag(orderDate), units = "h"), NA)) %>%
  summarise(total_hours = sum(hours, na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>        ID total_hours
#>     <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 4227631          24
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! There was one feature missing when the state 0 immediately follows state 1 and we weren't calculating the duration. I put the code above under my answer in the edit section.